# PHP how to remove extra characters at the end and beginning of a string

Tags: php

How can I get rid of extra hyphens at the end and beginning of user submitted text for example. I want `visual-studio-2008` instead of `-visual-studio-2008-` is there a way I can remove the extra hyphens using PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [trim](http://se.php.net/trim) and supply all characters you want to strip as the second parameter. In your case:

```
// Yields visual-studio-2008
$string = trim('-visual-studio-2008-' ,'-');
```

Answer (score 0):

use `trim(field,'-')`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0):

Use trim and have the second argument be a '-' character. That will remove the hyphens from the beginning and end of the string.

i.e. trim($string, '-')

For more: https://www.php.net/trim