# string pattern matching

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP how to remove extra characters at the end and beginning of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440635/php-how-to-remove-extra-characters-at-the-end-and-beginning-of-a-string)

I have strings like these :

**input:**

```
/help/detail.php
/page1/
page2/
/page3
```

**output:**

```
help/detail.php
page1
page2
page3
```

I want to remove `/` from a string if it exists in the beginning or in the end. / in the middle of the string is OK. I am always confused creating these type of matching string.

Thanks

Comment: *(reference)* http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression would be this:

```
preg_replace('^/+|/+$', '', $string);
```

But you actually don't need it, [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) will do the job in this case:

```
trim($string, '/');
```

Comment: closevoting dooplicatz. you haz the power to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Given to you in "sed" form: `s/^[/]*(.*)[/]*$/$1/` will remove any numbers of slashes in front of after the string. Inner slashes will be left untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `^` (matches beginning of a string) and `$` (matches end of string).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 echo trim('/page1/' ,'/');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strpos, strrpos and substr for this.

```
$string ='/help/detail.php'

## begin of string
$len=strlen($string);
if( strpos($string,'/') == 0 )
    $string=substr($string,1,$len);

## end of string
$len=strlen($string);
if( strrpos($string,'/') == ($len-1) )
    $string=substr($string,0,-1);
```